# Flutter new_version package gives range error - Stack Overflow

Tags: flutter, package

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1
> E/flutter (21407): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:281:36)
> E/flutter (21407): #1      NewVersion._getAndroidStoreVersion.

new_version package  returns this error. Here is my code Can you guys help?

```
    void _checkVersion() async {
    final newVersion = NewVersion(
      androidId: "myId",
    );
    final status = await newVersion.getVersionStatus();
    if (status!.localVersion == status.storeVersion) {
      newVersion.showUpdateDialog(
        context: context,
        versionStatus: status,
        dialogTitle: "UPDATE !!!",
        dismissButtonText: "Skip",
        dialogText: "Please update the app from " +
            "${status.localVersion}" +
            " to " +
            "${status.storeVersion}",
        dismissAction: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        updateButtonText: "Update Now",
      );
    }

    print("DEVICE : " + status.localVersion);
    print("STORE : " + status.storeVersion);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google have changed their return, before the version was returning on the ds:4 script, but now it returns at the ds:5 (The library is outdated)

If u change the line 183 from the new_version.dart to

before

```
(elm) => elm.text.contains('key: \'ds:4\''),
```

after

```
(elm) => elm.text.contains('key: \'ds:5\''),
```